# Error When Parsing Curl Api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5

I Have implemented this code. When I run it for the first time, it gives a response. But When I Run it the Second time, it gives error like....

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No value.) UserInfo=0x178265540 {NSDebugDescription=No value.
```

But Whenever I uninstalled and rebuild it gives response.

```js
 NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"type",@"st_eml",@"st_pwd",nil];
    NSMutableArray *value=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"normal", @"Huhn",@"1234", nil];
    
    //NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"type", @"st_eml", @"st_pwd", nil];
    //NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"normal", @"Huhn",@"123", nil];
    NSDictionary *theRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:value forKeys:data];
    
    // Serialize the data
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSData *theJSONData = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:theRequestDictionary error:&error];
    
    
    
    NSLog(@"Serialization Error: %@", error);
    
    // Change the data back to a string
    NSString* theStringObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    // Determine the length of the data
    NSData *requestData = [theStringObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    
       NSString* requestDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]];
    
    // Create request to send to web service
    
    NSString *strurl = @"http://testing.singletreffen.de/appapi/v1/login";
    NSString* webStringURL = [strurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:requestDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
    
    // Deserialize the response
    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error:&error];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, made some changes in parsing and it's working properly and giving response also

```
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"type",@"st_eml",@"st_pwd",nil];
    NSMutableArray *value=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"normal", @"Huhn",@"1234", nil];

    NSDictionary *theRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:value forKeys:data];

    // Serialize the data
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *theJSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:theRequestDictionary options:0 error:&error];


    NSLog(@"Serialization Error: %@", error);

    // Change the data back to a string
    NSString* theStringObject = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Determine the length of the data
    NSData *requestData = [theStringObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSString* requestDataLengthString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]];

    // Create request to send to web service

    NSString *strurl = @"http://testing.singletreffen.de/appapi/v1/login";
    NSString* webStringURL = [strurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:requestDataLengthString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Deserialize the response
    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error:&error];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"LOG : %@", returnString);
```

Comment: Some time it gives but Some time still same problem.